# React.js: passing data between two components to show accordion menu not working

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the content of a web page dynamically with ReactJS:

within my store.html:

```
<div className="row stores">
  <div id="Stores">
    <%= react_component('Stores') %>
  </div>

  <div id="Accordion-Store">
    <%= react_component('StoreAccordion') %>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user loads the page store.html, then only the store react_component('Stores') is visible. The react_component StoreAccordion is hidden (with css display:none).

```
// store_list.js.jsx
var StoreList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { showAccordionStore: false };
  },
  onClick: function() {
    this.setState({ showAccordionStore: true });
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <ul className="stores">
        <li id="Aarau"><a onClick={this.onClick}>Aarau</a></li>
        <li id="Bern"><a onClick={this.onClick}>Bern</a></li>
        <li id="Chur"><a onClick={this.onClick}>Chur</a></li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

When the user clicks on an li-element of ul.stores (within store_list.js.jsx) like Aarau, then the store_accordion.js.jsx is visible and the specific li of the accordion open.
That means to append css class "is-active" to li.accordion-item like

```
// store_accordion.js.jsx
var StoreAccordion = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { openAccordion: false };
  },
  emptyList: function() {
    return(
      <p>no stores available.</p>
    );
  },
  renderStoreAccordion: function() {
    return(
      <div className="row accordion-stores" style={{display: this.state.showAccordionStore ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
      <div className="accordion-account">
        <ul id="accordion-nile" className="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true" role="tablist">
          <li id="aarau" className="accordion-item {{display: this.state.openAccordion ? 'is-active' : ''}}" data-accordion-item data-allow-all-closed="true" role="tablist">Aarau</li>
          <li id="bern" className="accordion-item {{display: this.state.openAccordion ? 'is-active' : ''}}" data-accordion-item>Bern<li>
            <li id="chur" className="accordion-item {{display: this.state.openAccordion ? 'is-active' : ''}}" data-accordion-item>Chur</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  renderStore: function() {
    if (this.state.openAccordion === true) {
      return this.renderStoreAccordion();
    } else {
      return this.emptyList();
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return this.renderStore();
  }
});
```

I have two questions:

1) How to pass the variable showAccordionStore from store_list.js.jsx to store_accordion.js.jsx to show/hide with css style display: none

2) How to pass the id of the li element of store_list when it is clicked from store_list.js.jsx to the accordion li within store_accordion.js.jsx?
e.g. when the user clicks on Aarau then the corresponding accordion li should be get the css class is-active:
              Aarau

When i first load the page, the store_list.js.jsx will be rendered but not the accordion which is good. But after clicking on a store list item, the accordion will be still not rendered. Why is it so and how to fix it?

=== EDIT

In the Chrome Console i get this error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target
>   container is not a DOM element.

Comment: what is <%= react_component %> ?

Comment: this is rails embedded ruby code to execute a rails helper method for react. it just renders the react component. Sorry, i forgot to replace it.